# Android Navigation Graph not displaying start fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation-graph

I'm running into a wall debugging what should be a simple issue: I have an app with one activity, which contains a navigation graph, which should display a fragment on start. But it isn't.

`activity_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    >

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

`res/navigation/nav_graph.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/listFragment"
    >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/listFragment"
        android:name="org.example.my_app.ui.ListFragment"
        android:label="fragment_list"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_list"
        >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_listFragment_to_detailFragment"
            app:destination="@id/detailFragment"
            />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/detailFragment"
        android:name="org.example.my_app.ui.DetailFragment"
        android:label="fragment_detail"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_detail"
        />
</navigation>
```

`fragment_list.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.ListFragment"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="This should be visible"
        />

</FrameLayout>
```

`ListFragment.kt`

```
class ListFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_list)
```

Despite this dead-simple setup, I see a blank screen (just an app bar) and debug listeners added to the `ListFragment` class init don't ever get called. Why isn't my `navGraph` initializing an instance of the fragment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Documentation:

> NavHostFragment provides an area within your layout for self-contained navigation to occur.

You are missing to declare the fragment placeholder as a `NavHostFragment` in the `FragmentContainerView` via the `android:name` attribute; and therefore the navigation won't occur.

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    ....
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
```

Comment: Yes, that was it. Thank you, I've been staring at that block of code for hours trying to figure out what was missing.